# Forgotten SciFi Novel: World dominated by Competitions, Hero Won the 'Duet' Competition by 'under-singing'

Tags: story-identification

I read this years ago and often cite the premise to vocalist friends that a good duet is about blend, not competition, as wonderfully demonstrated in this story — and I am always disappointed that I've never been able to remember its title.
About the only concrete detail I can recall is that the whole realm was competition-based, and this was just one of many that the hero was involved in.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229122/series-of-stories-about-a-technologically-advanced-society-with-nude-masters-but (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably Blue Adept, the second in the [Apprentice Adept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept) series by Piers Anthony. The competitions on the world of Proton are a major plot point, especially the broad variety of such competitions involved. Although as far as I can tell, the duet competition in that book was a harmonica one (that being the favoured instrument of the protagonist).

> “Precisely. Now if you play a duet with one person, then with another,
>   and your performance stands improved on the second—?”
>
> “Then probably the other player is superior, enabling me to—“ Stile
>   paused. It was beginning to penetrate. “If I improve because of the
>   other player, it’s him that really makes the difference!”
>
> “When we played together, I improved more than you did,” Clef said.
>   “Who, then, contributed more to the joint effort? The one who flew the
>   heights—or the one who lifted him there?”
>
> “That duet—it was not to show individual expertise,” Stile said,
>   working it out. “It was to show cooperative expertise. How each person
>   fit in as part of a team. Yet surely the Computer did not see it that
>   way; the machine lacks the imagination. So it shouldn’t have—“
>
> “The machine was not the final arbiter. The musicians saw it that way,
>   and their vote was decisive.” The human mind remained more complex
>   than the most sophisticated of machines! Of course the musicians had
>   imposed their standard! “So I supported your effort—“

Comment: Thank you all - completely overlooked Piers Anthony as a candidate as can never see past 'Xanth', even having very recently re-read Incarnations of Immortality :/