# Book title request. (Magical worlds, unicorns, and androids) [Strong content]

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, parallel-universe

This book is one I have yet to be able to splice together enough to locate, I was 10-12 (Currently 48) The issue is that I read so many books of similar genres, that the stories jumble in recollection, so I have found some of what I remember as *a* book, have been multiple story lines converging in my memory. This may have been one book, may have been books in a series. I cannot even begin to estimate the books I read over my life, but at that age 3- a week was normal and 2 or more at a time was as well.

As remember this story line... I believe there was a person traveling alternate realities, sort of like cloud atlas style, but a single timeline not a progression over millennia. It had sexual undertones in some areas, rather explicit in others. In one timeline he was an android, and he and a female (as androids can be I suppose) companion  broke socially accepted norms or rules by exposing wires in their fingertips, that produced an intensely intimate and pleasurable experience when they touched them together (Implying some meta orgasm). This was something expressly forbidden. In another timeline his female companion was a human form unicorn. They were in a magical world, where he was learning how to harness magic. The unicorn "For some reason the name Leena comes to mind instantly when recalling" went into heat, and lest he lose her, he had to make sure she was properly mated so she did not have to follow instinct and leave to find a stallion of her kind. So he had to do so with the virility of a stallion (Since she was after all a horse/unicorn). When he fatigued he learned "magic" ways of making himself *capable* of mating again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This generally sounds like [Piers Anthony's Apprentice Adept series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept),
(*Split Infinity*, *Blue Adept* and *Juxtaposition*)though some of the details are slightly off, possibly due to length of time since you last read them. Or you read more of the series than I did.

The main character, Stile, is a serf on the technological planet Proton, and he discovers that he can "Shift" to the magic planet Phaze, where he can create magic spells using rhymes. He also plays the harmonica.

At one point, Stile, in a sort of relationship with a unicorn, needed to cast a "virility" spell on himself in order to, er, assist her when she is in oestrous.

I don't recall the android sex scene, but at one point Stile spends a lot of time with a "female" android and, given the social mores of planet Proton, both of them are always nude.

I hope that is enough information for you to either confirm or deny that these are the books you are thinking of.

Comment: I do remember the android sex scene. It's a different character than Stile, I think one of his children?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Well, Mach has some "forbidden" relationship with Fleta? - https://xanth.fandom.com/wiki/Out_of_Phaze

Comment: Ah, it's with Bane and Tilly, https://archive.org/details/outofphazeappren00pier/page/48/mode/2up?view=theater&q=wire

Comment: OMG, if I could send you a virtual gift basket and a bottle of wine, it would be there already! I cannot possibly thank you enough. I distinctly remembered "out of phaze" like a bell when I saw it! Leena-fleeta not too far off base, I would have been minimum 13 then, so 35 years later, close enough. Thank you all, I will be back to this place for sure! And I know what I will be purchasing in about ten minutes. Wow, I cannot wait to have these in my hands!!!!

Comment: @JohnWinkleman, I just checked your website. I am a sysadmin/developer too, for many years now the IT director for a nonprofit in TX. Managing everything virtualization to web service/site design. Lived in Derry as well in 96, Manchester till 2000! So my research project on how books shaped me as a person, appears to have some similar threads. You made my day, my week, my year. I just found a complete original paperback set, and they are on the way! Expensive paper, but they will help close a chapter of "me in retrospect" I have been looking for a very very long time. Thank you again!

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229122/series-of-stories-about-a-technologically-advanced-society-with-nude-masters-but is about the first book in the series.