# The magic and the mundane, man of two worlds

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I remember a book leant to me, middle-part of a series (?) in the early-mid 1990's, written in English.

The protagonist possessed the ability to move between the mundane world of his not-especially-exciting life into a magical world. In the real-world, he was no-one in particular, a dull job, single-life, small flat.

In the magical world, he was a wizard/sorcerer of great power, battling forces of chaos/evil. To enact the magics, he'd speak a spell - nothing special, just words which stated what needed to happen, but the condition was that they only worked once, a unique form of incantation per spell. Repeating an old spell's words didn't work.

On one cliff-hanger chapter-ending, in the real-world he received a gunshot, this wouldn't normally be a problem, as he would move to the magical world and transform the bullet/cure the wound - but on this occasion, an enemy from the magical world had made the bullet from a poisonous creature (chimera ?) such that if he moved to the magical world, the creature's touch would instantly kill.

The protagonist came-up with a neat solution which I forget.

Comment: The magic/mundane and unique incantations sounds a smidge like Piers Anthony's *Split Infinity* (and subsequent books in the series)... was the mundane world a tad sci-fi? Robots and a colony on planet Proton? LEXIBLE: Does a little Wikipedia reading… ***HOLY MOLY!*** Piers published 36 books in the *Xanth* series—also a magic/mundane fictional world—and books are still being published posthumously.

Comment: OK, there's a big haystack there, hadn't intended that. I'll see if I can find anything else to narrow it down. @Lexible

Comment: To be clear (in case I confused things): *Split Infinity* inaugurates one P.A. series, and the *Xanth* series is a different one.

Comment: @Lexible Piers Anthony isn't dead, there's nothing posthumous about Xanth,

Comment: @Lexible Piers Anthony is still alive.

Comment: @Moriarty Whoops! I totally thought I saw an obit a few years back. My mistake! No offense intended.

Comment: To eliminate a possibility: The part about how any given rhyming spell only works *once* made me decide that this is **not** a recollection of one of the "A Wizard in Rhyme" series of novels by Christopher Stasheff. As I recall, in the first novel the hero arrived from Earth and soon learned that most wizards preferred to use tried-and-true spells over and over, instead of risking their necks by chanting a new poetic creation which might misfire (and possibly kill them with the backlash of magical energy).

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73410/forgotten-scifi-novel-world-dominated-by-competitions-hero-won-the-duet-comp (which has an accepted answer)

Comment: @Otis I don't deny it could be, but the description in the answer (nor the question) seem even slightly familiar. It's a lead for me to follow, I'm sure I've read some of Piers Anthony's work at some point and I'll certainly check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is definitely one of the books from Piers Anthony's *Apprentice Adept* series — the "bullet" plot line clinches it. Let me go look exactly which book it is — < *Jeopardy* theme music plays > — it's the second book in the series, *Blue Adept*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] your answer to specify any other ways in which _Blue Adept_ matches the one described in the question, aside from the bullet plot point you already mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for this, only just noticed that you'd answered. Nice one.